# Save/download ArcGIS Online feature layer as shapefile using Python script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, feature-service, error-000210

I would like to go through my feature layers in my ArcGIS Online account and download/save the feature layers as shapefiles to my computer. I've tried [this](https://ago-assistant.esri.com/) tool and also [this](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-6496-download-arcgis-online-feature-service-or-arcgis-server-featuremap-service) and others but with no success. Now I'm trying to load the feature layers from the catalog to TOC in ArcMap. It works fine, I can see them in the TOC and I can copy them manually using *CopyFeatures* tool, or by right-click and then data-export data. Because I have a lot of feature layers, I wrote a script that will iterate over the layers and save them as *shp*:

```
import arcpy
import os
destPath = r"C:\Users\data from AGOL"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\data from AGOL\Untitled.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer == True:
       dest1 = os.path.join(destPath, str(lyr.name) + ".shp")
       arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr,dest1)
```

This works fine for some feature layers but for others it fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/untitled1/copyFeatures.py", line 15, in <module>
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr, dest1)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2429, in CopyFeatures
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\data from AGOL\AOI_151213.shp
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

The following image show one of the problematic feature layer (AOI_151213) and one that is OK (AOI_2015):

[image]

The only difference I can think of is that the problematic one, contain some txt files, but I can save it manually and it's fine. This error rises only in the iteration process.

Is there a way to modify my code so that:
- I will be able to save the problematic feature layer as shp file
- OR at least to add a condition that will not terminate the script, but skip this error (and the following errors) - I'm not sure how to embed such a thing.

Comment: I am wondering why the attempted output filename is different from the layername? AOI_151213 vs AOI_151213477954. I heard before that shapefiles have some limitations in filename and filepath length, but I could not that documented anywhere, so not sure if it's true.

Comment: hi, this is not the issue, I accidentally copied the error from one of my tries and not the first try. I edited the error.

Comment: The example you have given, is that exactly how you have been testing it? What if you tried a simpler path, with no spaces?

Comment: What software is this? By that I mean is the arcpy from ArcGIS Desktop or Server, and what version? And are you running the script standalone or from within ArcGIS?

Comment: The script was executed in pycharm, and GIS software is ArcMap 10.2.2 desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem was that there were 2 layers with the same name, but I'm not sure. Anyway, I modified my script so it will ignore all errors, because it is enough for what I'm trying to accomplished. The script that worked for me:

```
import os
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\data from AGOL\Untitled.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
destPath = r"D:\data from AGOL"
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer == True:
        d = lyr.name.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        file_name = d + ".shp"
        dest1 = os.path.join(destPath, file_name)
        print file_name
        print type(file_name)
        print dest1
        try:
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr, dest1)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. One not is that you may consider changing except: to except arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: so that you only pass over that specific error, and you may also want to print that error to the  console or a log file so you know you're missing a layer.

Comment: Note that with this approach you can only pull features up to the 'Max Record Count' set on the server, 1000 at default I think.